# Bound the Im. part of an trigonometric polynomial with its Real part

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been studying to see a solution to this question for almost a week and starting to feel a little bit dump, does anybody have an answer to this?

Let $$F(t) = \sum_{k=-n}^n c_k*e^{2\pi ikt}$$ be a polynomial of $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k e^{2\pi kit}$ with $F(0)=0$

Prove that exist for every interger $m>=1$ a constant $K_m > 0$ , independent of F, such that $$\int_0^1 [Im(F)]^{2m}   dt <= K_m*\int_0^1 [Re(F)]^{2m}  dt$$

Comment: Put exponents inside { }.